# Underscore js extend method

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, extend

Looks like Underscore library won't treat functions in JSON as first class citizens. Why doesn't this fiddle work?

http://jsfiddle.net/anV28/

```
var a = { 'f1': function(){var s='success';} };
var b = {'foo' : 'bar'};
var c = _.extend(b, a);
alert(JSON.stringify(c));

var d = _.extend({name : 'moe'}, {age : 50});
alert(JSON.stringify(d));
```

Why isn't `c` the right value?

`d` seems to have the right value if we only use strings as keys and values.

How can I get around this limitation?

Comment: This question let me remember the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) from John Resig again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`c` does have the right value:

```
{
    f1: function () {var s='success';},
    foo: "bar"
}
```

Your problem is that you're using `JSON.stringify` to produce strings for `alert`, there is no representation of a function in JSON so `JSON.stringify(c)` leaves `f1` out. If you use `console.log` to view your results you'll have better luck: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7j7hu/

As an aside, you should keep in mind that using [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) this way:

```
var c = _.extend(b, a);
```

will also modify `b` and that might not be your intent.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I would have never known the problem was with JSON.stringify